# Cannot open IIS 8 default site by private IP or localhost, yet IIS “browse” to by internal DNS works

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8, internet-explorer-11

Getting a **"HTTP 404 Not Found" when I enter the server's LAN IP in a browser** (http://192.168.1.70 - which the site has bindings for) or simply try to browse to localhost in IE 11. However, in IIS 8 I can successfully browse to "http://Server.MyDomain.com on 192.168.1.70" and everything works as intended. The static DNS A record already exists and was created for the hostname before I installed IIS 8 role.

  So far, I have tried:

Adding 192.168.1.70 and Server.MyDomain as trusted sites in IE

Deleting/re-adding the site in IIS

Restarting IIS Admin Servicing and rebooting the server.

What could be the issue here? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, PJ. I am indeed trying to use port 80 as the binding, yes. If I try to browse to http://localhost I get the 404 Error, just as I get with http://192.168.1.70 and/or http://192.168.1.70:80

Comment: If I ping MyServer.MyDomain.com I was getting only an IPv6 reply, so I disabled IPv6 on the NIC and now I just get ::1: (just loopback, I believe. There is no loss).

Comment: Everything is being done internally, just on the single web server right now. I think you're right in that it's a DNS issue, but I can't find anything wrong in DNS. I will re-enable IPv6 and see if the address that pings back to the hostname machines....

Comment: Just so I understand here, it ONLY works on the server when you go to `localhost` from network PC it does NOT work with `http://192.168.1.70` or `http://Server.MyDomain.com` correct?

Comment: Actually no, it only works with <!--http://Server.MyDomain.com--!> 

It does not work when I try to browse to <!--http://localhost--!> or <!--http://192.168.1.70--!>

Comment: I must have broken IIS 8 when I deleted all the default sites and added my own. I'm reinstalling IIS on the server now to start from scratch...

Comment: **FIXED IT!! Reinstalling IIS 8 was the solution.** 

Thanks again for your help, PJ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular case here, reinstalling the IIS 8 role was the solution.